# IMDb HTML Extraction - With Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, imdb, imdbpy

With **Beautiful Soup4**, I'm trying to get some text that doesn't seem to be tagged. (I may be wrong, I'm not very capable with HTML)

I need to extract several values from the IMDb code of the page; the budget value and the latest worldwide gross value for a particular film. The length of the code varies between films so if there is a method using *Beautiful Soup4* to extract these values regardless of the line number, that would be hugely helpful.
This is the code:

```
<div id="tn15content">
<h5>Budget</h5>
$165,000,000 (estimated)<br/>
<br/>
```

from the source code of this page: [IMDb Box Office page for Interstellar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/business?ref_=tt_dt_bus)

I need that '$165,000,000' to be extracted so I can store it etc.

The Gross code is even more confusing:

```
<h5>Gross</h5>
$188,020,017 (USA) (<a href="/date/03-19/">19 March</a> <a href="/year/2015/">2015</a>)<br/>$187,991,439 (USA) (<a href="/date/03-15/">15 March</a> <a href="/year/2015/">2015</a>)<br/>$187,930,551 (USA) (<a href="/date/03-14/">14 March</a> <a href="/year/2015/">2015</a>)<br/>$187,918,949 (USA) (<a href="/date/03-11/">11 March</a> <a href="/year/2015/">2015</a>)<br/>$187,888,097 (USA) (<a href="/date/03-08/">8 March</a> <a href="/year/2015/">2015</a>)<br/>
```

All I need from this is the most recent (the Worldwide figures are further through a huge chunk of code which I decided to leave out due to spacing on here.

I know there was a similar problem on here solved, however I couldn't get the solution to work nor could I comment to ask the user providing the answer for help with my particular solution due to being new to the site.
I was going to try and get IMDbPY to work, however I wasn't sure how to get it to install with WinPython.

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression

```
\$([0-9,]+) \(USA\)

\$([0-9,]+) \(Worldwide\)
```

http://pythex.org/